# python IDE for auto-complete Docstring

Tags: python, ide, docstring

I am looking for a Python IDE which can generate the docstrings framework for me automatically.
For example:

```
   def GetTextByCtrlName(self, _hwnd, _ctrName):
        '''
        @desc:

        @param:
             _hwnd 
             _ctrName  
        '''
```

Then I can just fill the corresponding content.

Answer (score 2):

[PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm) has supported this since version 1.5.

First, configure the format you want the docstring to be generated. Hit `CTRL`+`ALT`+`S` (on Windows), select the format in Project Settings > Python Integrated Tools.

Your choices are plain, Epydoc or reStructuredText

Once that is configured, make sure your cursor is on the method name and press `Alt`+`Enter`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a tool like [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/). It's designed to specifically document python code, although it doesn't offer a friendly IDE integration.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use Sphinx to achieve what OP is asking?